# Did the creators of Into Darkness research Khan?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-into-darkness, the-wrath-of-khan, star-trek-movies

Okay, so I just watched *Star Trek into Darkness* and as a long-time fan of *Wrath of Khan* I'm a little confused by the portrayal of Khan.  Okay, the actor is different and they clearly decided to take more than a few liberties with his appearance.  I'm more wondering about the portrayal, not the appearance.

In the original *Star Trek* show and in *Wrath of Khan*, Khan is ruthless but not unfeeling.  He is passionate and he cares about his followers and loves his wife who used to be one of Capt. Kirk's crew I think.  But I dunno, I guess I feel that his sense of pride and his ruthlessness combined with the kind of control and poise his super genetics give him means that he's not gonna start crying all of a sudden.

Compare this

[image]

to

[image]

Are these two Khans really part of the same persona?

[image]

They should be of course, because in theory the same two Khans from the twentieth century were woken up, it doesn't matter which timeline we're talking about.  So why are they so different?

Also, Khan talks about his "family" instead of his followers or fellow exiled leaders.  Khan may have called these people his family by the time of Wrath of Khan, after years and years in exile on that waste planet Kirk put them on dodging brain eating worms and such...but I just feel like "family" doesn't make sense here in Into Darkness.  I'm also not sure why Khan is working on weapons design and starships and stuff like that.

It seems like they've used Khan in name only.

So my question is: did the writers do any background research on Khan at all, or did they just make him up completely on the spot and just re-used the name?

I do know they *intend* him to be the same Khan, but I'm wondering how hard they tried.  Did they say what kind of research they did?  Did they say they wanted to take him in a new direction and if so how do they justify the change in personality and skills?

Sorry if I've rambled, just trying to make my case clear, that's all.  Thanks.

Comment: +1, your third image immediately reminded me of [ThunderCats](http://thundercats.wikia.com/wiki/ThunderCats_Wiki). Must be the hair...

Comment: Yes, I guarantee that the creators of a multimillion dollar movie researched Khan. And they took artistic license. It's a damned-if-you-do damned-if-you-don't situation. You make him the same, and people accuse you of lack of creativity. You make him different and you piss off treckie purists. They took the route that was more interesting.

Comment: @MishaRosnach perhaps they should have made an original screenplay instead if a trite remake of wrath of khan to indulge their artistic license, then. "let's reboot the universe to tell new stories that are actually just the old ones warmed over!"

Comment: @Shamshiel: Well, the thing about making movies is you do whatever the hell you want. If you prefer the old Wrath of Khan movie, don't worry - it's still there.

Comment: The comparison is apples to oranges because you are comparing a Khan that has woken up recently and has been trying to manipulate starfleet for a few years, versus a Khan that has spent some 20 years surviving in an empty hostile planet with nothing after being defeated by a plain human. The more fair comparison would be between the "Into the Darkness" Khan and the Khan in the TOS episode "Star Seed". I have never actually watched "Star Seed", so I don't know how that fares.

Comment: @EuroMicelli : It's called "Space Seed" dude.  And I was factoring that into my comparison.  I wrote "In the **original Star Trek show** and in Wrath of Khan, Khan is ruthless"... I wouldn't say his personality changes between Space Seed and TWOK. Part of my whole case is that he doesn't consider the other exiles to be his "family" in "Space Seed", maybe just respects them as equals.  They were rulers of different countries who were actually at war and then all punished in the same way.  The family thing only develops 20 years later, which is why it doesn't make sense in Into Darkness.

Comment: A cute explanation I read is that the bioengeneered knew that one of them might be woken before the others.  And they all agreed that whomever was woken first would call themselves Khan as a kind of information warfare: deny useful information to your captors.  Being Khan, that woken person would be more valuable than if they where some random super-human, and they all where capable of the role.  And if there was a real Khan that was something special, this would hide his identity...

Comment: Abrams has stated that his movies are intended as a reboot for a more modern and younger audience, no guarantees that anything will be the same as it used to be. In fact it's probably safe to expect otherwise; that's kind of the point of a reboot.

Comment: "I guess I feel that his sense of pride and his ruthlessness combined with the kind of control and poise his super genetics give him means that he's not gonna start crying all of a sudden." Why? Is crying a sign of weakness or lack of control any more than angry outbursts (which Khan had plenty of) or laughter? Maybe it's been seen that way for 20th century Americans, but there's plenty of tears in the heroic tales of other cultures. As for why he was doing weapons design, are you forgetting that he was engineered to have a superior intellect? (even if Kirk was laughing at it in TWOK)

Comment: @Hypnosifl -- You're kind of missing my point.  I'm asking about why the two portrayals differ, not about if the Into Darkness portrayal is reasonable or not on its own.

Comment: @TylerH  No.  It's not a true reboot, it's an alternate timeline.  Before they split off, everything should be the same. That's what Joachin is saying.  Khan was frozen before the new timeline started.

Comment: @Joachim - But the question can only be answered if one agrees the portrayals do in fact differ, so it's relevant to bring up the argument that the two versions don't seem essentially different.

Comment: @Hypnosifl They may not seem essentially different to you, but I think that legions upon legions of Star Trek fans would disagree with you, pal.  There's really not much in common between the original Khan and this "Khan", sorry to say.  I kinda like Yakk's theory above.  It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Legions of Star Trek fans may just be distracted by superficial differences like the accent (easily explained in terms of Khan trying to pose as a local, and having plenty of time to pick up the accent) and the actor's physical build, not to mention many predisposed to dislike the new Trek movies. In terms of character, Khan was always a pretty simplistic villain, there's never been much more to his character than "arrogant, suave superintelligent guy who wants to show off his superiority over ordinary mortals by gaining power over them", and that's as true of the new version as the old.

Comment: @InlandEmperor He was frozen prior to the split, but awoken after it.  Everyone seems to underestimate the effect experience has on a person, completely ignoring that the original Khan spent 20 years awake with his comrades, while the new Khan spent only a few years awake alone, being manipulated by Star Fleet.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: Sure. But if I mine a franchise for characters and settings then shit out a vapidly generic action movie script on the grounds I think that'll produce more cash than typical Star Trek, I shouldn't expect to have my decisions excused on the grounds of 'artistic license'.

Comment: @Shamshiel: I'd try not to become personally invested in the continuity and dependability of fictional universe franchises.  Directors tend to have a tumultuous relationship with the status quo, and producers see profit in controversy.  Pissing off purists isn't just fun, it's good business.  That said, this stuff's there for your enjoyment - take what you like, leave what you don't.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: I care not a whit for Star Trek continuity, which would be silly in a franchise that itself consists of mostly independent series and has only halfheartedly cared. I'm not a 'purist', I just recognize that it's ridiculous to pretend inserting characters with high name recognition into a generic, formulaic, algorithm-approved action movie script (with bonus lens flares) has anything to do with 'artistic license' or creativity. It's just a bad, lazy movie, and the only reason it made money is because people wanted to see Star Trek and/or things blow up.

Comment: You can't guarantee it. E.g. the movies of Starship Troopers and World War Z are nothing at all like the originals.

Comment: Plus Montalban could act; Cumberbatch not so much. His one thing is staring into the camera then flaring his nostrils.

Comment: @Shamshiel: Well, it sounds like your problem isn't really with resetting the Star Trek universe by changing Khan (a very minor character within the Star Trek universe, actually), but with visually-centered action movies. Which is your prerogative, needless to say - but even so, 87% critic score and 90% audience score on Rotten Tomatoes, $228 million total gross. Millions of viewers would beg to differ.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the old universe khan that we see is from 2285.  The new one is from 2259. Old universe, he was discovered in 2267 instead.  Khan from [TOS: Space Seed](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Seed_(episode)) would be a better comparison.

Comment: @MichaelT : I *was* comparing "Space Seed" to *Into Darkness*.  I mention the episode in my question.  Also read my response to EuroMicelli above.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It would seem that the writers, Robert Orci, Alex Kurtzman, and Damon Lindelof, were aware of Ricardo Montalban's original portrayal of Khan in *The Original Series* and *The Wrath of Khan*, but explicitly chose to depart from it.

First of all, they recognized that Khan was a character of immense importance in the *Star Trek* canon:

> Lindelof said that Khan was considered a character they needed to use at some point, given that "he has such an intense gravity in the Trek universe, we likely would have expended more energy NOT putting him in this movie than the other way around."

The statement about having to expend energy to keep Khan out of the film is fairly contrived, but it does imply that they were at least aware of the character's importance.

> References to *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan* were eventually added to the script, but **Lindelof, Orci, and Kurtzman "were ever wary of the line between 'reimagined homage' and 'direct ripoff'."** Orci and Kurtzman said they wanted a film which would work on its own and as a sequel, **not using ideas from previous Star Trek works** simply "because you think people are going to love it".

So it seems that they made a conscious decision to depart from the previous notion of the character.

([Source for Excerpts](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness#Development))

To shed more light on the process by which Khan — or at least a version of the character — came to be in *Into Darkness* and why he was portrayed as he is, I include the following snippets from an interview with Orci from the official *Star Trek* web site:

> **INTERVIEWER:** Let's talk about Khan (Benedict Cumberbatch). Take us through why you went with Khan as the villain and, also, can you clarify why he does what he does?
>
> **ORCI:** OK, I’ll do a deep dive with you. In a way, [fellow co-writer and co-producer] Damon [Lindelof] and I were the biggest debaters about this. He argued for Khan from the beginning and I argued against it. **The compromise that we came to was, let us devise a story that is not reliant on any history of *Star Trek*.** So, what's the story? Well, we have a story where our crew is who they are and they're coming together as a family. Then, suddenly, **this villain arrives and his motivations are based on what happens in the movie. They're not based on history. They're not based on Star Trek. They’re not based on anything that came before. They're based on his [being] used by a corrupted system of power that held the things he held dear against him and tried to manipulate him.** That story stands alone with or without *Star Trek* history. That's how we approached it, and God bless Damon for going down that road.
>
> So, once we had that, that's when Damon came back and reared his ugly head and said, "OK, now that we have that, is there any reason why we cannot bring *Star Trek* history into this?" And he was right. So we ended up sort of reverse engineering it. We started with, "What's a good movie? **What’s a good villain? What’s a good motivation? We cannot rely on what's happened before.** Now that we have that, can we tailor this villain into something that relates to *Star Trek* history?" And that’s what we did. So, step one was "Don’t rely on *Star Trek*." Then, step two was "Rely on *Star Trek*."

([Source](http://www.startrek.com/article/exclusive-orci-opens-up-about-star-trek-into-darkness-part-1))

Within this, we find that Khan's behaviour differs from his counterpart in the Prime Timeline (i.e. the timeline that would have developed if it weren't for Nero's interference in the 2009 film) because of

- the manipulation and abuse that Khan received at the hands of Admiral Marcus (this is the **in-universe answer**);
- they conceived of their villain and his qualities before they decided he would be Khan Noonien Singh (this is the **out-of-universe answer**).

As for the issue of Khan crying, it seems to be compatible with this explanation.  That being said, it was probably included as a means of adding an extra dimension or layer to the character — although I agree with the OP that it is ill-fitting at best.

Comment: Okay, wow, that's a lot of info, more than I expected.  Thanks!  And I like your handle and avatar.  Star Trek 6 was a great movie.

Comment: @Joachim : Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: ...So basically the answer is no. IMHO, it was a bad approach to take. They're alienating the people that want to see the film most, those that loved Khan when he quoted Shakespeare and turned straight guys temporarily gay.

Comment: @PointlessSpike They might be alienating some old fans but they've successfully opened it up to a much wider audience as the film was quite well received. And I don't just mean general audiences; there are even a lot of scifi fans that never got into star trek due to it's age.

Comment: @slicedtoad- I absolutely get that, but the two goals are not mutually exclusive. You can honour the old stories and characters and simultaneously set up a decent storyline that'll appeal to modern audiences.

Comment: One point you've missed. He's not actually crying, he is faking it to manipulate them.

Comment: @JamesRyan : An interesting point, but it's hard to say.  There are no notes in the screenplay to suggest that he is faking.  Also, in *Into Darkness*, Khan does seem to have an extreme emotional attachment to his so-called "family".

Comment: @Praxis doesn't one of the characters specifically flag it to kirk?

Comment: @JamesRyan : No, at least not in that particular exchange.

Comment: "So it seems that they made a conscious decision to depart from the previous notion of the character." -- The quote doesn't say that though, I would interpret "not using ideas from previous Star Trek works" as not using specific plot points or lines (even though they did at the end, annoyingly), rather than not having the characters be similar (since they obviously did try to keep the characters pretty similar in the case of the *Enterprise* crew)

Comment: @Hypnosifl : You're selecting only one quote.  But then we have "..this villain arrives and his motivations are based on what happens in the movie. They're not based on history." This quote from Orci has to do with Khan as a character.  It says that Khan's persona and behaviour have been fit to their storyline.  So I disagree.  (Although I agree that the particular quote you have selected can only be interpreted as far as you have done in your comment.)

Comment: That second quote just says his motives aren't a retread of his motives in TWOK (wanting vengeance for being stranded on Ceti Alpha V), because he has a different life history since the point he was revived from suspended animation, not that the character's psychology and persona are any different.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Perhaps persona is the wrong word, but I am referring to his behaviour *after* his capture by Admiral Marcus.  In any case, the comment area is an inappropriate place for *extended debate*.  If you would like to debate this further, please create a sub-room in chat and ping me. :-)

Comment: But if you are "referring to his behaviour after his capture by Admiral Marcus", you are talking about your interpretation of what the movie shows about his character, whereas your answer suggested that clear evidence of a changed character can be found in quotes from people involved in production--I was disputing the latter, not the former, just pointing out I don't think the intended meaning had anything to do with their desire to change his basic character, as opposed to changing specific plot elements and aspects of his post-revival history from what we saw in "Space Seed" and TWOK.